# Understanding internal torques

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, solid-mechanics

I have having trouble with Q7: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXGgW.png

I don't understand how to find internal torque, the solutions say that the internal torque is equal to the external torque.

So I can find the torque for the sections, however the solution says that after 0.4m (the second sprocket) there is no internal torque. This is the part I don't understand. Why is there no internal torque?

Shouldn't it be the same internal torque for the entire part from 0.2m to 0.55m since it's receiving the same torque from the motor and so the torque on this part of the bar is the same as it has the same dimension for this part?

Answer (score 1):

End B is free to rotate. There is no resistive torque applied to it, and it is not accelerating. So the torque on the section S2B is zero.